# Reference to another cell in between strings

Tags: excel

Is there a way to refer another cell in excel in between strings.
For example in one cell i have.

```
<string name="greeting">Hello! How are you?</string>.
```

Is it possible to make "Hello! How are you" a function which refers to other cell and get value from it and replace "Hello! How are you?".Let's say b6 contains "Good" I want content of b6 to replace "Hello!How are you?"so new contents of the line would be "Good instead of "Hello! How are you?. If possible could you please provide me with solution. I know you can use "=" to call function/formula if its in beginning. How to use it in between strings? I have tried placing "=" in-between strings but it considers it as normal string.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You mean something like `="Hello! How Are you "&B1`? This formula will return `Hello! How Are you ` and the text in cell `B1`

Comment: Have a look at [ask] a question with a [mcve] and edit your question accordingly. That way it will become more clear what it is you are after. =)

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Your solution works only if I start the cell with "=" , here I want to add formula in between strings. Here It will take "=" as a normal string. And I don't want to combine I want to replace the contents. Meaning I want to replace "Hello! How are you?" with contents of B1. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you want to have "=Hello! How are you?" replace itself with the value of a cell when you place it in a formula.

This can be done with named ranges. You can call the cell you need to call "Hello! How are you?", via Formula's > Name manager.

You can then call it in your formula like so: `=Hello! How are you?` which will return the value of the cell with that name. This can be used in other formulas like `=IF(Hello! How are you? >5, Hello! How are you? +1, 12)` which will test if the value in the named range is bigger than 5, and return the value + 1 if so, or number 12 if not.

Please note, the name you have chosen will not work, and is unnecessarily long to begin with. It's best practise to keep names short and to the point. You can not use special characters other than `_`. This includes spaces. So your example would have to be called `HelloHowAreYou` or `Hello_How_are_you`. But just using `Hi` would work best.

Comment: I have edited my question to add line in my excel sheet as block of code, my requirement is to replace "Hello! How are you?" with content of another cell. Let's say b6 contains "Good" I want content of b6 to replace "Hello!How are you?"so new contents of the line would be "<string name="greeting">Good</string> instead of "<string name="greeting">Hello! How are you?</string>. Thanks for your time